# Where are Race The Sun save files stored?

Tags: race-the-sun

I believe on a Mac they are in ~/Library/Preferences/unity.Flippfly.RaceTheSun.plist

Where are they on Windows?

Is there any way to copy them from my Mac to my PC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, the save file is stored in the registry on Windows.

If you want to find it in regedit, it's under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER > Software > Flippfly > RaceTheSun`.

Comment: Be careful with Regedit.